# Android: count number of app launches

Tags: java, android, mobile

I need to count the number of times the user launches an app. I'm storing the value in a shared preference, and putting the count logic inside `onCreate()`.

Now, since `onCreate()` is called in a number of different scenarios, not all of which include the user actually launching the application, I'm using the saved instance state bundle to store a flag set in `OnSaveInstanceState()` -- if the flag is absent, I consider the user started the app manually.

Is this necessary, or is just checking for a `null` bundle passed to `onCreate()` enough? In either case, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thank you all for your answers. They all helped some way or another.

That said, after several tries and different approaches, I think there is no actual 100% reliable way of determining when the user has launched the app. None of the activity life-cycle callbacks can really be used tackle the issue, neither individually nor combined.

The closest I got was counting the number of `onResume()` calls, and then substracting from it in `onPause()` depending on the return of `isFinishing()`. This approach, however, doesn't account for the home button, among maybe other things a user can do to hide apps.

I will update this answer if I ever find a way to do this reliably.

Comment: If you are looking to limit user access to your app before they pay, is there some other interaction with the application that you can record and limit?

Answer (score 3):

You could call `getCategories()` on the intent to see if it includes the LAUNCHER catagory.

Comment: It won't include the LAUNCHER category if the user navigates away from the app and then back, without relaunching it?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure, but that would be easy for you to test.

Comment: How? As far as my understanding goes, onCreate may or may not be called again -- maybe just onResume, maybe not.

Comment: log the `getCategories()` method in both onResume and onCreate, and monitor logcat.

Comment: This isn't a bad line of thinking... possibly use an intent filter to detect where the intent was started from.

Answer (score 1):

You could think about this another way... increment the counter every time onDestroy() is called.  This way you would be guaranteed that the program is actually out of memory, and the counter will only ever be off by 1 at most.

Just throwing an idea out there, hope it gives you some more of your own!

Comment: Don't want the counter to go up? Pull the battery!

Comment: THEY'RE TRYING TO SPY ON ME!  I GOTTA PULL THE BATTERY

Answer (score 1):

A `null` check in `onCreate()` should work just fine. No need to set a separate flag in `onSaveInstanceState()`. There is one possible issue though.

Say the user put your application in background (by pressing home key). The application process will eventually get killed. When the user restarts the application, you will receive a proper `Bundle` object in `onCreate()` with the flag set. The user can prevent your counter from being incremented by simply backgrounding your application everytime.

If backgrounding could be an issue, you might try something like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() == null) {
        counter++;
    }
}

public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return new Object();
}
```

I have used the above code before and it works on Eclair, FroYo and Gingerbread. It seems `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` have been marked deprecated in Honeycomb, so I am not sure how it will work in case you are targeting Honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `onCreate` method, include a check to [`Activity#getCallingActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity()). It returns `null` if the app was not started from another activity.